# How to test entity framework execution strategy?

Tags: entity-framework-6

We have an Entity Framework execution strategy coded in our lower environment. How do we test this to show it's actually working? We don't want to release to Prod without something to say we aren't introducing new problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to use some listener where you can throw an exception and subscribe this listener to the `dbContext`.

```cs
    public class CommandListener
    {
        [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandExecuting")]
        public void OnCommandExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, Guid commandId, Guid connectionId, bool async, DateTimeOffset startTime)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException("Test exception");            
        }
    
        [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandExecuted")]
        public void OnCommandExecuted(object result, bool async)
        {
        }
    
        [DiagnosticName("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command.CommandError")]
        public void OnCommandError(Exception exception, bool async)
        {
        }
    }
```

Subscribe listener to `dbContext` f.i. in `Startup.cs`

```cs
    var context = provider.GetService<SomeDbContext>();
    var listener = context.GetService<DiagnosticSource>();
    (listener as DiagnosticListener).SubscribeWithAdapter(new CommandListener());
```

As `TimeoutException` is transient exception in `SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy.cs` (if you use the default retrying strategy) you will get `TimeoutException` as many as your `MaxRetryingCount` of strategy setting has. Finally, you have to get `RetryLimitExceededException` as a result of the request.

You have to see `TimeoutException` in your app logs. Also it is good idea to turn on transaction logs `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction": "Debug"`

What I did to manage to throw the transient exception and debug strategy (testing and playing around purpose only)

1. I added `ExectuionStrategyBase.cs` and
   `TestServerRetryingExecutionStrategy.cs`. The first one is clone of
   `ExectuionStrategy.cs` and second one is clone of
   `SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy.cs`
2. In Startup.cs I set retrying strategy

   ```cs
   strategy services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(options =>
       {options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), sqlOption =>
           {
               sqlOption.ExecutionStrategy(dependencies =>
               {
                   return new TestSqlRetryingStrategy(
                       dependencies,
                       settings.SqlMaxRetryCount,
                       settings.SqlMaxRetryDelay,
                       null);
               });                   
           });
   ```
3. In `OnCommandExecuting` of `CommandListener.sc` I just checked some static `bool` variable to throw or not `TimeoutException` and in `ExectuionStrategyBase.cs` I swithced that variable.

Thus, I managed to throw transient `Exception` on the first execution of the query and successful execution on the second short. Now I think about some long running transaction and kill session of this transaction in SSCM during execution of it.

Also, I found out that if there is a query like
`var users = context.Users.AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync()` execution strategy is not implemented and I am stuck on it. I have been struggling with that a couple of days but still can figure out nothing. If remove `AsNoTracking` or replace `ToArrayAsync()` by something like `FirstAsync()` all foes well.